# Updating in MongoDB without first having to pull a Mongoid object?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid

When performing queries I can go through Mongoid:

```
product_obj = Product.where(
                            _id: "58f876f683c336eec88e9db5"
                           ).first # => #<Product _id: 58f876f683c336eec88e9db5, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, sku: "123", name: "Some text", ...)
```

​
or I can circumvent it:

```
product_hsh = Product.collection.find( {
                                         _id: BSON::ObjectId.from_string("58f876f683c336eec88e9db5")
                                       }, {
                                         projection: {
                                          _id: 1,
                                          name: 1
                                        }
                                      } ).first # => {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('58f876f683c336eec88e9db5'), "name"=>"Some text"}
```

I prefer to circumvent, because it performs better; I can limit which fields to get in the response.

My problem, however, is how to further work with the returned product. The response is a hash, not an object, so if I have to update it I need to pull it through Mongoid anyway, and thereby the performance gains are gone:

```
Product.find(product_hsh["_id"]).update_attribute(:name, "Some other text")
```

My question is: how do I update without first having to pull a Mongoid object?

Comment: can you format the first code block differently? The horizontal bar is covering the code for me.

Comment: @Tiramisu done.

Comment: the update command lets you specify the filter document and the update document. If you know the documents that you need to update then you can do so in a single statement. Look at the .update or the $set documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pull/fetch at all. You can just send the `$set` commands directly:

```
Product.where(id: product_hsh["_id"]).update_all(name: "Some other text")
```